# Ifelse according to lookup

Tags: r, vector

I have a `data.frame` named `expC` in which I would like to create a new column by looking up if the characters in one column `spc` equals the characters assigned in a lookup vector:

`east <-c("AL","CB","CM","CO","EN","HA","HP","IG","IP","LU","NR","PE","RM","SG","SS","WD")`

For characters in `expC$spc` in the `east` vector, return `1`, if not return `0`.

I would much appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: please provide an example of your data and expected output

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
expC$ee = as.numeric(expC$spc %in% east)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the trouble CB, this saves me so much time! It worked perfectly. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ifelse`

```
# dummy data
east <- letters[1:5]
expC <- data.frame(spc = sample(letters, 100, replace = T))

expC$newVar <- with(expC, ifelse(spc %in% east, 1, 0))

> head(expC)
  spc newVar
1   q      0
2   q      0
3   q      0
4   w      0
5   b      1
6   r      0
```